# Can anyone explain why I have lost 40 points recently?

Tags: support

In Biblical Hermeneutics I now appear at the bottom of the heap with minus 41 points.  Normally you are informed of any recent achievements, reputation, badges and privileges earned.  But I can't find anything over the past month to indicate why I lost 40 points.  I know I lost 2 points recently for down-voting an answer, which is perfectly acceptable.

I'm not about to lose sleep over this, but why have I not been notified of the reason for the loss?

Comment: [This question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/56876/2757) and your answer were deleted automatically by the system. I'm not too sure why.

Comment: @curiousdannii - it's a closed negatively voted question by a deleted user. The system has cleaned it up automatically

Comment: @Steve upvoted answers normally prevents deletion though.

Comment: @curiousdannii - only on Open questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88996/711957

Comment: @Steve Ah, yes. Though that's the answer to what we were discussing in chat I think.

Comment: @Stevecanhelp - Appreciate how you can prevent answers from being deleted, but sadly, not on this occasion.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Appreciate you guys looking into the matter, and for the explanation.